# Send node response ten by ten when endpoint requested

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, next.js

I'm building a web app using Next.JS and Node.
I also created my own API with node which is requested by Next.JS.

One endpoint that i call send data to my front as an array, and then i'm displaying the content of each object of the array.

But sometimes, my array contains hundreds of objects and i can't display them all at one time because it would make to much processing and data for the browser.

So i want to make my API (Node) to send me objects of the array by batch.

I'd like to pass a body to a Post request like:

```
{
...,
"length": 10
}
```

and the node sends me the first 10 objects, then the second 10 objects ...

Does someone know how to implement that ? Are there some libraries or anything else helping to build that ?

Have a nice day,
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can achieve sending data in batches using pagination concept on backend. Only thing you need to pass from frontend is page-no
Following is a simple example of pagination you can achieve

```
app.get('/api/posts', (req, res) => {
  const pageCount = Math.ceil(posts.length / 10);
  let page = parseInt(req.query.p);
  if (!page) { page = 1;}
  if (page > pageCount) {
    page = pageCount
  }
  res.json({
    "page": page,
    "pageCount": pageCount,
    "posts": posts.slice(page * 10 - 10, page * 10)
  });
});
```

Hope ,this shall give you an idea to implement pagination

Comment: Thank you sir, I implemented that and it works totally fine! Had no idea of the implementation behind that. thanks !

Comment: Good to know that it worked. Please mark my answer as correct so that other folks can get the correct answer if they faced the same issue